# Hooks for inspecting claims Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Lets say I have two Azure functions:

```
public static class MyFunctions
    [FunctionName("DoIt")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoIt(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log)
    {}

    [FunctionName("DoSOmethingElse")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoOther(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log)
    {}
}
```

And then I configure the Function AppService to require AzureAD authentication. Lets say I wanted particular permissions like Role membership or other claims. I could do the following in a function I call at the top of each method:

- inspect the `req` parameter for the bearer token, parse the JWT
- look at the claims
- Use AuthenticationContext or another JWT library to get Microsoft Graph tokens to get additional data

My question is are there options to do any of the following?

- Create "before hook" function so every http function I write in that class or deploy to the service container goes through this inspection
- Performa any of these authorization via attributes?
- Access a claimsIdentity directly?

Comment: I will try to post some more code later today.

Answer (score 2):

I've found some code sample related to what you are looking for:

- [stuartleeks/AzureFunctionsEasyAuth](https://github.com/stuartleeks/AzureFunctionsEasyAuth/blob/master/src/FunctionWithAuth/AuthFunctions.cs) (Github)

So the interesting part is here (will give you the main idea):

```
[FunctionName("GetClaims")]
public static HttpResponseMessage GetClaims(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
  HttpRequestMessage request,
  TraceWriter log)
{
  if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      var claimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
      var claims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToDictionary(c => c.Type, c => c.Value);
      // Could use the claims here. For this sample, just return it!
      return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, claims, "application/json");
      }
      else
      {
        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Not Authorized");
      }
    }
```

The simplistic solution would be to create a function that get the claims and you can call this function in every others functions.

Azure functions has [Function Filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters) (As per the documentation it is still in preview.)

> Function Filters provide a way to customize the WebJobs execution pipeline with your own logic. Filters are very similar in to ASP.NET Filters. They can be implemented as declarative attributes that can be applied to your job functions/classes.
>
> Filters allow you to encapsulate common logic to be shared across many different functions. They also allow you to centralize logic for cross cutting concerns (e.g. validation, logging, error handling, etc.).

So you should be able to create a custom authorization filter with these information.